# checkboxGroupInput - execute multiple functions by string in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

As an example, suppose I have three distinct "functions" `fun1(),fun2() and fun3()` that output a number `#1, #2,  and #3` respectively.

If I use the following option in shiny:

```
checkboxGroupInput("selec",label = h3("Select function"),
 choices = list("fun1" = 1,"fun2" = 2, "fun3" = 3))
```

then I can run the "function" I choose (one at a time), but how can I run all the ones I choose?,

For example, if I choose `fun1 and fun3`, I want the output of the functions `#1 and #3`

if I choose `fun1 and fun2`, I want the output of the functions `#1 and #2`

If I choose them all, I want all the outputs

Thank you for a help

Comment: Hi albert, you mentioned sthg about multiple outputs. I thought it is covered by the answer? Maybe you could provide more details,..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combination of `do.call` (for the function calling) and `sapply()` (for iterating over the array), see below:

```
fun1 <- function() return("#1")
fun2 <- function() return("#2")
fun3 <- function() return("#3")

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("functions", "Choose functions:",
                     choiceNames =
                       list("fun1", "fun2", "fun3"),
                     choiceValues =
                       list("fun1", "fun2", "fun3")
  ),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$txt <- renderText({
    print(sapply(input$functions, do.call, args = list()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```